# Unity 3d: Cam settings change after hitting play button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity 3d and trying to adjust a third person camera. The rotation settings change after I hit the play button. Does anyone know why ? I have attached two screenshots that show the problem.

[image: Before hitting play]

[image: After hitting Play]

Comment: Your OrbitCamera script is probably telling the Camera object to look at the player (Target), which would cause the camera to rotate in order to see the player. If you disable the script I'm sure it would stop rotating.

Comment: If you want to keep the camera attached to the ThirdPersonPlayer parent,
Parent an empty to the object, not the camera itself, and in Update set the camera to use that empty's x and z positions. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1007695/is-there-a-way-to-lock-my-cameras-rotation-and-mov.html